# How modify WEKA source code to support persian text?(utf8)

Tags: java, weka

I want to use result of weka classification and cluster in my program. How can I use  persian(utf8) data in weka? I use TextDirectoryLoader to load my text files and when I want to store my data in .csv format it doesn't save in correct format.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change `RunWeka.ini` file  in weka folders .you can use this solution to fix your problem:
http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Reading-utf8-arff-files-td15810.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var loader=new weka.core.converts.TextDirectoryLoader();
loader.setcharset("UTF-8");
```